# printing of composed unicode characters in luatex, e.g. u with small e on top

Tags: unicode

I want to print a lowercase u with a small e on top (u\868). I can insert 
the character into the code and see it in the browser (even here!), but the result is just 
a plain u. The MVW:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

some text with an u with e char: uͤ which does not print

\end{document}
```

I have experimented with different fonts, but not found a solution. How can 
i achieve printing the unicode I can see? 
[image]

Comment: You need a font that has the glyph, for instance Libertinus Serif or EB Garamond, among the free ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a font that has the glyph:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}

some text with an u with e char: uͤ which prints

\end{document}
```

[image]

On my machine it's in

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect! how can one find out which fonts have some character and which character are in a font?

Comment: @user855443 That mostly depends on your operating system and the available utilities. I'm on macOS and UnicodeChecker is great for this.

Comment: @user855443 https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0364/fontsupport.htm is useful for finding fonts.

Comment: Real useful - it is hard to find all the links to connect from a font to its usage in a latex file!